# Requesting Time Based Values from Amazon's search page

Tags: json, excel, vba, web-scraping

The code I'm using below will return/capture the keyword/phrase suggestions from Amazon's search bar. The problem is that there seems to be time based values in the parameters used to construct the output. Can I use a GET request to obtain the current time based values, or is there a better method? The code below is used in conjunction with JSonParser to get the suggestions. The result I’m looking for is the output of the code to match the drop down results from the Amazon search bar.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetTable()

    Dim json As Object, suggestion As Object                '<  VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Const SEARCH_TERM As String = "TRAVEL"
    Const SEARCH_TERM2 As String = "BOOKS"
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://completion.amazon.com/api/2017/suggestions?session-id=141-0042012-2829544" & _
        "&customer-id=&request-id=7E7YCB7AZZM1HQEZF2G1&page-type=Search&lop=en_US&site-variant=" & _
        "desktop&client-info=amazon-search-ui&mid=ATVPDKIKX0DER&alias=aps&b2b=0&fresh=0&ks=76&" & _
        "prefix=" & SEARCH_TERM & "&event=onKeyPress&limit=11&fb=1&suggestion-type=KEYWORD&suggestion-type=" & _
        "WIDGET&_=1556820864750", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)("suggestions")
    End With

    For Each suggestion In json
        Debug.Print suggestion("value")
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the only time-related parameter that I can spot in the query string is the parameter `_`, which has a value of `1556820864750` and appears to be an Epoch timestamp in milliseconds. Is your question how can you replace the `1556820864750` with a current Epoch timestamp?

Comment: What changed each time was the 'session-id' and/or the 'request-id'. So, more of a clarification might be that each 'time' I send the request these two parameters may change. So, I'm wanting to get those ID's prior to sending the request so I I can replace that portion of the code with the current parameters.

Comment: I haven't looked at the Amazon API, or what it has to say about how it defines and uses the `session-id` and `request-id`. I would think, though, that in cases like this that the `id` is a unique identifier to track a session and requests (obviously). But for an interaction such as this, the `id` field may be generated by an algorithm based on time, location, demographics, or just a completely random string. Is there any information you have on this `id` other than what you've stated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those params values can be removed except the session-id. They are actually cookies values. For the session-id you can generate a value for far into the future and that should last for a while.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetTable()
    Dim json As Object, suggestion As Object, suggestions As Scripting.Dictionary '<  VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Const SEARCH_TERM As String = "TRAVEL"
    Const SEARCH_TERM2 As String = "BOOKS"

    Set suggestions = New Scripting.Dictionary
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://completion.amazon.com/api/2017/suggestions?session-id=999-5000000-8000000" & _
        "&customer-id=&request-id=&page-type=Search&lop=en_US&site-variant=" & _
        "desktop&client-info=amazon-search-ui&mid=ATVPDKIKX0DER&alias=aps&b2b=0&fresh=0&ks=76&" & _
        "prefix=" & SEARCH_TERM & "&event=onKeyPress&limit=11&fb=1&suggestion-type=KEYWORD&suggestion-type=" & _
        "WIDGET&_=", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)("suggestions")
    End With
    suggestions(json(1)("widgetItems")(1)("metadata")("text")) = vbNullString
    For Each suggestion In json
        suggestions(suggestion("value")) = vbNullString
    Next
    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In suggestions.keys
        Debug.Print key
    Next key
End Sub
```

Comment: QHarr-thank you for the response. So how would I send the request to just retrieve those values? What would the syntax look like?

Comment: Wait, QHarr, are you saying that those values aren’t needed to obtain the real time results I’m looking for?

Comment: Yup. I believe so. Try running the above.

Comment: I ran it, but the output doesn't match the dropdown suggestions I see from Amazon. It seems to be the same as before.

Comment: Ok.... Will have a proper look. Can you update  your question to include the expected results please?

Comment: I updated the question as you requested, QHarr. Thank you!

Comment: QHarr - that seems to have done the trick! Thank you so much for your solution!

Comment: Hopefully that will last for quite some time but let me know.